# Count formula across mutliple cell ranges

Tags: excel

I’m trying to get a count of the number of matches between two ranges of cells but I don’t know which formula (or sets of formulas) to use to accomplish this

I’ve tried =countifs() but it doesn’t work since the criteria for the formula is a range and excel doesn’t like it.

Data set 1:

| Carrier | PY | Claim nbr |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2012 | 123456 |
| B | 2012 | 567890 |
| C | 2012 | 222365 |

Data set 2:

| Carrier | PY | Claim nbr |
| --- | --- | --- |
| C | 2012 | 222365 |
| A | 2012 | 123456 |
| B | 2012 | 567890 |

Comment: Some sample data has been added :)

Comment: have you tried adding two Countifs?